# Chart.js number fomat with data attribute

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Using [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) v.2 library,I want to add commas to numbers, so I have created a function called `addCommas`.

I have read official chart.js document and it does not specify the way to set tooltipTemplate config uisng data attribute.

I have also tried to set `Chart.defaults.global` using javascript and it did not work.

Any suggestion or advice would be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Here is my code below.

```
<canvas data-chart="line" data-labels='["2016-10","2016-11","2016-12","2017-01","2017-02","2017-03"]' data-values='[{"backgroundColor": "    (96, 125, 139, 1)", "borderColor": "#666", "borderWidth": 2, "pointBackgroundColor": "#50b432", "pointRadius": 1, "label": "매출액", "data": '["196267000","157179000","159363000","166962430","242801860","139650000"]'}]' data-hide='["gridLinesX", "legend"]' data-tooltips: '{"custom":"<%= addCommas(value) %>"}' height="150" width="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you provide your `addCommas` function?